# Orbeon: How to display orbeon form description in PDF?

Tags: orbeon

Currently while **generating PDF** , PDF is displaying **Form Title**.
Is there any way it will also display **Form Description** of the same form ?

Form Description I am referring is as per bellow pointer :

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the CSS used. By default, there is a rule like this:

```
@media print {
    .fr-form-description { display: none; }
}
```

You would have to add a stronger (or placed after) rule doing for example:

```
@media print {
    .fr-form-description { display: block; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, .fr-top .fr-form-description { color: black } .fr-top .fr-form-description { display: block }

Answer (score 0):

I have to add following class in form-runner-orbeon.css ( @media print { })

.fr-top .fr-form-description { color: black }

.fr-top .fr-form-description { display: block }